# What algorithm does GeoPandas use for calculating distances between polygons?

Tags: python, algorithm, distance, geopandas

I'm using ArcGIS Pro and GeoPandas for spatial analysis operations. I noticed that the distance operations in ArcGIS and the GeoPandas don't align. I wonder which algorithm GeoPandas uses for its distance calculations (function distance).

In my example I selected polygons within a distance of 10 km from another polygon. One polygon is selected in ArcGIS but not in GeoPandas as the distance there is > 10 km. The data is projected to the same crs in both cases.

It's not surprising that different distance algorithms are used, I just can't find any information on which algorithm GeoPandas uses. I already checked the [documentation](https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.distance.html?highlight=distance#geopandas.GeoSeries.distance) and the [code in Git](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas).
ArcGIS uses vertex distances for polygons (ArcGIS documentation [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/how-near-analysis-works.htm)).

Has anyone background information on the GeoPandas distance tool algorithm?

Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of dependencies `geopandas` relies on. For the distance computation that involves point to point object, it uses `shapely` Euclidean distance as can be traced to this link:- https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/blob/master/shapely/geometry/base.py

If you have a geodataframe `df5` like this

```
   a  b                 geometry
0  0  1  POINT (0.00000 0.00000)
1  0  2  POINT (1.00000 0.00000)
2  1  3  POINT (0.00000 2.00000)
3  5  4  POINT (1.00000 1.00000)
```

You can do computation check with

```
df5.geometry.values[0].distance( df5.geometry.values[3] )
```

The result will be 1.4142135623730951, which is the Euclidean distance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess I didn't formulate my question specific enough. I noticed the disalignment for polygons. Do you know which algorithm is used for polygon-to-polygon distances? In the link you shared it's not explained.

def distance(self, other):
        """Unitless distance to other geometry (float)"""
        return self.impl['distance'](self, other)

Answer (score 0):

There is no exact explanation for this in the shapely documentation. However, it can be estimated that

https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#shapely.ops.nearest_points is likely to be used.

So I think it will represent the minimum distance between two polygons.

However, this is just my opinion, and I think you will have to test it yourself in the end. In my experience shapely doesn't produce the closest points other than the points shown on the polygon. (You can see this in an example where shapely calculates the minimum distance between a point and a line. The minimum distance is not the distance along the vertical tangent, but the closest point to the line's vertices.)

Since it is based only on points that already exist in polygons, I think that there may be a difference between the two values if ARCGIS finds and calculates the contact point with the minimum distance.